# How to migrate asp.net mvc to asp.net core with asp.net identity framework database first

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-identity, ef-database-first

I have a database first asp.net mvc application now I want to migrate it to asp.net core with all my identity tables and use it like database first. I research a lot but could not find any reasonable source.

Comment: Could help: https://blog.devart.com/migrating-entity-framework-6-projects-to-entity-framework-core-1-entity-framework-7.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want to migrate from asp.net mvc to asp.net core you should check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/mvc?view=aspnetcore-5.0) link
and for more information about migrate identity too , check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/identity?view=aspnetcore-5.0) link .